# Several issues after cloning Ubuntu 20.04 onto new SDD with Clonezilla

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, sound, graphics

I recently bought a new computer and I wanted to move my Ubuntu 20.04 installation from my old one over to my new one, along with all the files on the machine. I searched around and found one of the recommended ways to do it is to use Clonezilla so I followed the steps here to perform a [disk_to_local_disk](https://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/03_Disk_to_disk_clone) transfer by moving the old SDD into the new computer, running Clonezilla on a USB and following the above steps. It mostly worked, all my apps are running, but I have several issues after the switch.

I should also mention that I have a Windows 11 installation on another SDD on this computer. They both boot fine, but after I cloned the Ubuntu image to the new hard drive, regular booting time has drastically increased.

1. Ubuntu is not recognize my graphics card. I have VGA controller when running `lspci | grep VGA`

`01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2216 (rev a1)`

But when I run `sudo lshw -C video` there's no model output. My graphics card is a NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080. On my old computer Ubuntu recognized the NVIDIA Geforce GTX 970 and ran fine. If I try to install the NVIDIA drivers and run them it uses the integrated graphics card.

2. My AUX ports aren't being correctly recognized. I have an aux port at the top of my case that works fine on Windows, but when I switch to Ubuntu it only works on the rear aux port.

When I run the command `alsamixer -c 1` the "sound card" with id 1 is my webcamp for some reason `HD Pro Webcam C920`. The other "sound cards" listed are `HDA NVidia` and `USB Audio`

My sound card is integrated into my motherboard, but for some reason it is not being recognized.

I've gone through several search results for both the above issues, but my issues seem relatively unique, any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: If Windows 11 based system, it must be new, and then really needs 22.04 to have latest kernel & driver. And if different video like nVidia (or does not have nVidia & old one did) you may have to add or delete driver. I usually suggest a new clean install & restore from backup. Backup should include everything you need & if something missing, then you can add that as you still have old system. Minimum is /home & list of installed apps. While I had backkup, I just rsync'd over local network my data from old system to new system after newe install. Faster than flash drives.

Comment: I'll try upgrading to 22.04 and see what happen, the original system has a Nvidia 970, the new one has a Nvidia 3080. The odd thing is, Ubuntu recognizes that it's a Nvidia card, it just doesn't recognize which version of Ubuntu it is.